# Polymorphic calls effecting local members with pointer/reference

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I came across a weird situation today while coding and I'm hoping someone could shed some light onto why this is happening.

I have a list of pointers to some base class:

```
std::list<BaseClass*> m_list;
```

Then I get one of the BaseClass pointers from this list

```
BaseClass* pBase = m_list.front();
```

Then I turn this base class into one of its child classes. (This is where I think the weirdness comes into play)

```
pBase = new ChildClass(*pBase);
```

The ChildClass uses the BaseClasses copy constructor to copy over all of BaseClasses fields.

Now with this ChildClass I call one of BaseClasses methods to set a field in BaseClass.

```
pBase->SetSomeIntMember(10);
```

Now if I check this int value it is 10 as expected, but it appears to only be changing it locally because if I get this same ChildClass from the list again and check it's int member it will be unchanged.

Hopefully this wasn't too tricky to follow. What makes this happen? In any situation where there is no polymorphism involved it would obviously not only be a local change as we have a pointer to the class instance. I'm guessing that I'm stomping on the pointer when I create a new ChildClass, but it definitely makes the BaseClass from the list become a ChildClass because the virtual methods still work.

Comment: `ChildClass->SetSomeIntMember(10);` isn't valid code, do you mean `pBase-> ...`?

Comment: Indeed I do. Edited it, thanks!

Comment: Also, `pBase = new ChildClass(pBase);` will not invoke the copy constructor for two reasons: 1) the copy constructor takes a `const&` parameter, not a pointer; and 2) the argument should be of the same type (or a derived type), not a base class object.  Unless a `const ChildClass&` can be obtained from the argument, the copy constructor will not be invoked.

Comment: I dereference the pointer to actually pass by reference to invoke the copy constructor. Edited to be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You copy the value of the pointer, not a reference to the pointer.

That is,

```
BaseClass* pBase = m_list.front();
pBase = new ChildClass(*pBase);
```

is not the same as

```
Baseclass*& pBase_r = m_list.front();
pBase_r = new ChildClass(*pBase_r);
```

Remember, if you want to update the original value, you need to use references or pointers.

**Note**

The second example contains a memory leak since the original value of `pBase` is discarded before `delete`. To avoid such surprises, use smart pointers, e.g. `std::shared_ptr<T>` (C++11) or `boost::shared_ptr<T>` in place of `T*`.

Do *not* use `std::auto_ptr<T>` because its semantics are not compatible with STL containers.

So your list class should be `std::list<std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>>`. Another advantage here is that you can use instances of the smart pointer instead of references without messing up the internal reference count.

Comment: You should also add that the second snippet causes a memory leak since the object that `m_list.front()` previously pointed to has not been `delete`d

Answer (score 3):

```
 pBase = new ChildClass(pBase);
```

This doesn't "make the BaseClass from the list become a ChildClass". It creates a **new** instance of ChildClass. Only changes to `pBase` done in `ChildClass`'s constructor could affect what `pbase` pointed to before. (You cannot make one class "become an instance of a child class".)

That line of code does not change `m_list` at all. `m_list` still contains a pointer to the original `BaseClass` object.

Answer (score 2):

at first look you were just assigning the newly allocated pointer by value to pBase. The list element is actually the pointer address which got copied by value to pBase. The list element actually didn't get changed

try this instead

```
BaseClass** pBase = &(m_list.front());
BaseClass* pOld = *pBase;
*pBase = new ChildClass(**pBase); // you have a leak here of *pBase BTW 
deleteOrCleanup(pOld); // cleanup or delete the old pBase pointer 

//do what you were doing
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, your problem is that you're simply modifying the local copy of a pointer, and not what it's actually pointing to.

Instead of sticking raw pointers into containers and having to manually delete them (or leaking memory) when you try to replace container elements, use smart pointers.

```
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

struct base
{
  base( int a )
  : x(a)
  {}

  int x;
};

struct derived : base
{
  derived( int a )
  : base(a)
  {}
};

int main()
{
  std::list<std::unique_ptr<base>> mylist;
  mylist.push_back( std::unique_ptr<base>( new derived(10) ) );

  auto pbase = mylist.front().get();    // get raw pointer to first element
  std::cout << pbase->x << std::endl;

  pbase = new derived( 10 * pbase->x ); // create a new derived object
  mylist.front().reset( pbase );        // replace the first element, previous 
                                        // element is deleted automatically

  pbase = mylist.front().get();
  std::cout << pbase->x << std::endl;

  // all allocated objects will be automatically deleted
  // when mylist goes out of scope
}
```

Output:

```
10
100
```